# Vaadin widgets on client side

Tags: java, gwt, widget, client-side, vaadin

Hy everyone!

I want to make multiple widgets in Vaadin 7. But my goal is, they only communicate with each other on the client side. Is it possible in Vaadin 7? And if yes, then how? Please submit a simple code.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the event bus for the communication on the frontend?

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/event/shared/EventBus.html